How to use KOMA fonts in scrlttr2
I am used to use {\titlefont Title-like Emphasis} to typeset a few words in the style of the title font but all attributes else like in the surrounding text. It is one of the nice features provided by KOMA classes that make coherent typography easy, without sacrificing flexibility.
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
{\titlefont Title-like Emphasis} works fine in article-like KOMA classes.
\end{document}

However, this does not work in scrlttr2 class:
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\begin{document}
{\titlefont Title-like Emphasis} is broken in the KOMA letter class.
\end{document}

This is rejected with ! Undefined control sequence..
My first idea was to \usepackage{scrextend} since this is meant to provide KOMA extensions to arbitrary classes:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}

\begin{document}
{\titlefont Title-like Emphasis} from \texttt{scrextend} works with many, but not all classes.
\end{document}

This works for an article document as advertised. But for the scrlttr2 class, the command \titlefont still won't be found (I'm on TeX Live 2024).
How do I typeset text in title font when using the scrlttr2 class? I am not dependent on using \titlefont specifically; if there is another equally robust/easy way to switch to the headline font and back, I'd be fine with that too.

@cfr scrlttr2 and scrletter also support a title.

@cabohah thanks. is that a standard thing in german letters?

@cfr Don't know. But scrlttr2 does not only support German letters, so maybe this was a request from somewhere else somewhere in the word.

@cabohah thanks. Letter formats seem highly prescriptive and conventional, which isn't surprising, I suppose. (i.e. now I'm curious!)

\titlefont is deprecated for decades (AFAIK since KOMA-Script 2.95 in 2006). So your first example should be:
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
{\usekomafont{title}{Title-like Emphasis}} works fine in article-like KOMA classes.
\end{document}

for very, very long time and the same would also work with scrlttr2:
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\begin{document}
{\usekomafont{title}{Title-like Emphasis}} works fine in article-like KOMA classes.
\end{document}

or IMHO better:
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\begin{document}
{\usekomafont{lettertitle}{Title-like Emphasis}} works fine in article-like KOMA classes.
\end{document}

Note: For compatibility title is an alias of lettertitle with scrlttr2. In contrast, only the lettertitle element is defined by the scrletter package. In the scrletter wrapper class, the title element comes from the scrartcl class and is independent of  element lettertitle, which comes from package scrletter.
However, titles in scrlttr2 usually should be defined using \setkomavar{title}{…}, e.g.:
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\begin{document}
\setkomavar{title}{This is the title}
\begin{letter}{You\\There}
  \opening{Hi,}
  and
  \closing{Goodby}
\end{letter}
\end{document}


See the KOMA-Script documentation (available in English and German) for more information about \usekomafont, \setkomavar and the predefined elements and their default font settings.
